# How do I define a stored procedure that returns table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

For example I have this stored procedure:

```
create procedure MyStoredProcedure
as
begin
    select  *
    from X,Y
    where x.Id = Y.ID
end
return @table table(X.tTitle, Y.Description)
```

I want return table and when use table in another query

Comment: do you mean return another table ?

Comment: no i want return result of stored procedure(table) and use it in another query

Comment: Hi...you mean you got result as a table which have 3 columns(suppose). and you want to pass specify column as a argument on another query...Right? now, i am looking for. - how many column you want to pass as a argument on 2nd query?  - is this work on same SP or any another platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored procedures cannot<sup>1</sup> be composed into other queries as a source of rows - is there a reason why it *has* to be a stored procedure? A [user defined function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) has almost the same amount of expressability as a stored procedure and *can* easily be a source of rows in the `FROM` clause of another query.

Something like:

```
create function MyFunction()
returns table
as
return (select  X.tTitle,Y.Description
    from X
    inner join Y
        on x.Id = Y.ID)
```

<sup>1</sup> Ignoring `INSERT`...`EXEC` since it does nothing for composition, and `OPENROWSET` isn't always a viable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
create procedure MyStoredProcedure
as
begin

select  X.*,Y.*
    From X INNER JOIN Y ON X.Id=Y.ID

end
```

This will select all data from tables X and Y.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This Way:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]

    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        Declare @ID int
         set @ID =(select ID From X INNER JOIN Y ON X.Id=Y.ID)
         IF @ID > 0
         BEGIN
               return @table table(X.tTitle,Y.Description)
         END
    END
```

Comment: i use result of stored procedure no create stored procedure  for example   Select * from my storesprocedure as result,X    where x.id= result.id

Comment: I am Confused what you actual wants? Can you Explain For me

Comment: do you mean by execute another storedprocedure by using query in this procedure ?

Comment: i create my stored procedure  and when  exec  it  i want to do somethin on it for example  select *  from exec mystoredprocedure as result,x       where result.id=x.id

Comment: create another procedure to use result of this procedure

Answer (score 1):

you can simply Create a `Procedure` and then, Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT  tTitle ,
                Description
        FROM    X
                JOIN Y ON Y.ID = X.ID
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temp tables or table variables.
Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE
(
COLUMN DEFINITION
)

INSERT INTO #TABLE
EXEC <YOUR STORED PROCEDURE>
SELECT *
FROM #TABLE

DROP TABLE #TABLE
```

You can insert your stored procedure inside the temp table so you can use it as well as a table.
Note that temp table names should start with #.

Comment: i use result of stored procedure no create stored procedure for example Select * from my storesprocedure as result,X where x.id= result.id

Comment: ok you can insert your stored procedure result into temp table and them use temp table like a table. Insert into #table EXEC <SP> .

Comment: But also you can use view instead of stored procedure for your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Somethings like this you most write

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <SP_Name>
AS
BEGIN
    Select ......
End
```